# Can anyone please tell how to center this RED div?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone please guide as to how can one center this "Red" div (div="red") both horizontally and vertically inside the grey (parent) "wrapper" div? I want the red div to be exactly positioned in the center (both vertically and horizontally) to the wrapper div. Here is the code:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 249, 249, 1);
  margin: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
.red {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  height: 50%;
  width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
  /* [disabled]line-height: 100px; */
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  /* [disabled]z-index: 1; */
  left: 0%;
  top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.green {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: block;
  /* [disabled]z-index: -1; */
  margin: 0px;
  clear: none;
}
.blue {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 51, 153, 1);
  left: 400px;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 100px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  Test
  <div class="red">Red
    <div class="green">Green</div>
    <div class="blue">Blue</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything you need to know about centering can be found on the [awesome CSS Tricks site](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by adding this to your `.red` in the css:

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Here is an example:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 249, 249, 1);
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}
.red {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  height: 50%;
  width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.green {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
}
.blue {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 51, 153, 1);
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  Test
  <div class="red">Red
    <div class="green">Green</div>
    <div class="blue">Blue</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: I cleaned up your css. I removed many unnecessary lines. You can compare them to your own code. Also a tip: There is no need for the type if the value is `0`, so `0px`, `0%`, `0em` or whatever can be written as just `0`.

Comment: top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%); seems to work perfectly. can you please explain what exactly it does?

Comment: Yes I can. `top: 50%` will put the top of the `.red` div in the middle of the parent div (`.wrapper`). The `transform: translateY(-50%)` pulls the `.red` div to the top for 50% of it's own height.

Comment: But this thing fails when we resize/rescale the browser window. All the div's dont scale accordingly. whats the solution to that?

Comment: I made a fiddle for my explanation. The first three seconds you see the `top` going from `0` to `50%`, then you see the `transform: translateY` going from `0` to `-50%`. Hover your mouse over the grey area. I added a div for clarity so you can see whats the middle of the wrapper. https://jsfiddle.net/w0tsvLc7/1/

Comment: The solution to scaling might be using percentages for the `width` and using properties like `min-width` to set a minimum.

Comment: can u giv example?

Comment: You can check out media queries. Here's a link: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp. Also, if you think my answer was the solution to your problem, you can click the checkmark on the left of my question so people know that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

In order to center vertically / horizontally, I suggest to use flex.

Your grey container only need thoses properties, and the red one doesn't need anymore margin/positions properties like `top: 50%`, `bottom: 0`, etc... :

```
display: flex;
align-items: center; // Vertically center content
justify-content: center; // Horizontally center content
```

Here a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/JCornat/yz8qLqk8/)